# Simple Ajax Autocomplete example, can't get to work with PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, autocomplete

I saw a video on youtube that did exactly what I try here. I cannot get it to work. This is what I am using:
https://www.devbridge.com/sourcery/components/jquery-autocomplete/

I have put all the files under the project folders directly and tried this:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.autocomplete.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body>
<h1>Autocomplete Input</h1>
<input type="text" id="autocomplete"/>

<script>
$('#autocomplete').autocomplete({
    serviceUrl: '/search.php'
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

and search.php is

```
<?php
echo json_encode(
    array(
        'suggestions' => array(
            'United Arab Emirates',
            'United Kingdom',
            'United States'
        )
    )
);
?>
```

Simple as it gets, but can't seem to work. I really tried to make this work, if someone could take a look. The styling is correct, the functionality isn't where. Im typing in words starting whit "Un.." and nothing happens.

Comment: Specifically, what doesn't work?

Comment: you find any error?

Comment: `serviceUrl: '/search.php'` doesn't look right. You'll need a `source` and something to load the PHP file in that (AJAX, GET, etc..)

Comment: Use `json_encode()`  in your PHP to make JSON - don't format it yourself

Comment: the php , must return json data echoing an array won't do it, it's invalid json data. Take a look at the example in link about what the server side must return .

Comment: @FakhruddinUjjainwala look at the referenced api....that is not correct

Comment: @FakhruddinUjjainwala did you test it using the plugin that OP is using? It's docs have no `source` and clearly have `serviceUrl`

Comment: @charlietfl oh ok. Got it. My bad :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the webpage you linked: https://www.devbridge.com/sourcery/components/jquery-autocomplete/#jquery-autocomplete-response-format

The response needs to be JSON. If you're echo'ing it yourself, you need to write it as a valid object (note the `{` and `}`):

```
echo '{ "suggestions": ["United Arab Emirates", "United Kingdom", "United States"] }';
```

Better would be to let PHP handle the JSON formatting:

```
echo json_encode(
    array(
        'suggestions' => array(
            'United Arab Emirates',
            'United Kingdom',
            'United States'
        )
    )
);
```

Comment: Funny story: 'search.php' should be used without the slash. Hahah